# Count and list all posts user has posted in all categories

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, charts

I have just discovered this awesome wordpress function

```
<?php echo 'Number of posts published by user: ' . count_user_posts( ); ?>
```

Im busy making a graph which displays on a pie chart how many posts the user has done per category. (chars.js)

Is there any way to make a loop almost where i could get the values for each category the user has posted in.

Id like to future proof it so if more categories are added i dont have to go and write something like this

```
<?php echo 'Number of posts published by user: ' . count_user_posts( 5 ); ?>
<?php echo 'Number of posts published by user: ' . count_user_posts( 7 ); ?>
<?php echo 'Number of posts published by user: ' . count_user_posts( 8 ); ?>
```

Is there a way where i can just get a category breakdown of how many posts a user has posted in all categories

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the [count_user_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts) function. It's argument is for user id and not for category id.

Anyways, once you have the desired user id (if i understood well, you want to display the post count for every category where the user was the post author) you can do something like this:

```
$user_id = 124;

/* Get all categories */

$categories = get_terms("category");

/* Loop for each category to count the posts of the user */
foreach($categories as $category)
{
   $cat_name = $category->name;
   $cat_id = $category->term_id;
   $post_count = count(get_posts("cat=$cat_id&post_author=$user_id"));

   echo "The user $user_id has $post_count posts in the $cat_name category";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

Just set which type of user's do you want at array:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'blog_id'      => $GLOBALS['blog_id'],
    'role'         => 'subscriber',//"Super Admin" or "Administrator" or "Editor" or "Author" or "Contributor"
    'meta_key'     => '',
    'meta_value'   => '',
    'meta_compare' => '',
    'meta_query'   => array(),
    'include'      => array(),
    'exclude'      => array(),
    'orderby'      => 'login',
    'order'        => 'ASC',
    'offset'       => '',
    'search'       => '',
    'number'       => '',
    'count_total'  => false,
    'fields'       => 'all',
    'who'          => ''
 ); 

php get_users( $args );

foreach ($blogusers as $user) { ?>
        <li>
            <?php $user_id = $user->ID ?>
            <?php echo 'Number of posts published by user: ' . count_user_posts( $user_id ); ?>                 
        </li>   
<?php } ?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the completed code, thanks for the help everyone

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pieData = [
                            <?php
                                $user_id = get_query_var('author');

                                $rand = array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');

                                //get all posts from author
                                $args = array(
                                    'post_type' => 'post',
                                    'author'=> $queried_object->ID
                                );

                                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                                if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

                                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

                                        //put categories in array
                                        $cat = get_the_category( get_the_ID() );
                                        $terms[] = $cat[0]->term_id;

                                    endwhile;

                                    wp_reset_query();
                                endif;

                                //count matching categories (array vals)
                                $countVal = array_count_values($terms);
                                foreach($countVal as $count){

                                    $color = '#'.$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)];

                                    echo "  {
                                            value: ".$count.",
                                            color:'".$color."'
                                            },";
                                }

                            ?>
                            ]
                            var myPie = new Chart(document.getElementById("piec").getContext("2d")).Pie(pieData);
                        </script>
```